# Weird output for weights/filters in CNN

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

My task is to visualize the plotted weights in a cnn layer, now when I passed parameters, `filters = 32` and `kernel_size = (3, 3)`, I am expecting the output to be 32 matrices each of 3x3 size by using `.get_weights()` function(to extract weights and biases), but I am getting a very weird nested output, 
the output is as follows:

`a = model.layers[0].get_weights()
a[0][0][0]`

`array([[ 2.87332404e-02, -2.80513391e-02, 
         **... 32 values ...**,
        -1.55516148e-01, -1.26494586e-01, -1.36454999e-01,
         1.61165968e-02,  7.63138831e-02],
       [-5.21791205e-02,  3.13560963e-02,   **... 32 values ...**,
        -7.63987377e-02,  7.28923678e-02,  8.98564830e-02,
        -3.02852653e-02,  4.07049060e-02],
       [-7.04478994e-02,  1.33816227e-02, 
        **... 32 values ...**, -1.99537817e-02,
        -1.67200342e-01,  1.15980692e-02]], dtype=float32)`

I want to know that why I am getting this type of weird output and how can I get the weights in the perfect shape. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape of the kernel weights from a Conv2D layer is `(kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1], n_input_channels, filters)`. So in your case

```
a = model.layers[0].get_weights()
print(a[0].shape)
# should print (3,3,z,32) if your input has shape (x, y, z)
```

If you want to print the weights from one of the filters, you can do

```
a[0][:,:,:,0]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your answer, it worked really fine, thanks again :)

Comment: Hey, I see that the second layer is different from the first one, can you tell me how to visualize the weights from the second layer and also what is happening behind the covers, so I can grab weights for all the layers.

Answer (score 3):

Weights in neural network are values that represent connection strength between input nodes and output nodes(or nodes in next layer).
Conv2D layer's weights usually have shape of (H, W, I, O), where:-

- H is kernel height
- W is kernel width
- I is number of input channels
- O is number of output channels

Conv2D weights can be interpreted as connection strength between a patch of input channels and nodes in output filter/feature map. This way you would have weights of shape(H, W) between each Input channels and each Output Channels. It should be noted that the weights are shared among different patches of the same channel.

Consider the following convolution of (8, 8, 1) input with (2, 2) kernel and output with (8, 8, 1). The weights of this layer has shape (2, 2, 1, 1)
[image]
The same input can be used to produce 2 feature map using 2 (2, 2) filters as follows. Now the shape of the weights would be (2, 2,1, 2).
[image]

Hope this will clarify how to interpret the shape of convolutional layers.

Comment: Thanks so much, it did clarified my understanding ^_^

Comment: Hey, can you elaborate or refer me the source to learn about what happens between two layers? Like this was my first Conv2D layer and after that, there is my 2nd Conv2D layer, what happens between both these layers(how filters work)?